# Applying CSS and removing CSS on .keypress and deletion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am trying to modify a form. Styling the `data-placeholder` didn't really succeed and I've turned to jQuery.

So the style for the placeholder is

```
input[data-placeholder] {font-style: italic;}
```

which is fine.

Now I've needed to turn it to "normal" when the user is typing the data and I did this with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var allInputs = $(":input");
  $(allInputs).keypress(function() {
    $(this).css('font-style', 'normal');
  });
  preventDefault();
});
```

Now when user deletes the text the placeholder remains "normal".

I need to set the `data-placeholder` to `italic` when the user deletes the text. So, I need to make it revert to the old settings upon the deletion of the text.

I did try this:

```
$(function() {
    var allInputs = $(":input");
    $(allInputs).keypress(function() {
        $(this).css('font-style', 'normal');
    });
    preventDefault();
    if($(allInputs).val().length === 0) {
        $(this).css('font-style', 'italic');
    }
});
```

but it didn't work and I don't know why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes that handles the entire placeholder functionality. This is working with the fact that you are using data-placeholder rather than placeholder. You should probably be able to remove the plugin and only use this.

**CSS**

```
input[data-placeholder] {
  font-style: italic;
}

input[data-placeholder].selected {
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:text").each(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).data('placeholder')).focus(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == $(this).data('placeholder')) {
        $(this).val('').addClass('selected');
      }
    }).blur(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).val($(this).data('placeholder')).removeClass('selected');;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**[Working JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8nddme0L/1/)**

Comment: This affects my #submit_btn input. I've tried including .not(), but didn't work.

Comment: Small change. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

give your data attribute a value and you do not have to set styles via JS.

```
input[data-placeholder="1"] {font-style: italic;}
input[data-placeholder="0"] {font-style: normal;}
```

and js could look like

```
$('input[data-placeholder]').keypress(function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $(this).data('placeholder', 0);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just CSS

```css
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   font-style: italic;
}

input:-moz-placeholder { 
   font-style: italic;  
}

input::-moz-placeholder { 
   font-style: italic;  
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   font-style: italic;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter text">
```

Comment: Please read the question. I don't have a placeholder, only data-placeholder. Tried this already, didn't work.

Comment: Because I don't have a placeholder, this is part of jQuery plugin. Only the data-placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to check when an action is happening:

```
$(allInputs).on('blur input change', function(){
    if($(allInputs).val().length === 0) {
        $(this).css('font-style', 'italic');
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens is, lets say I have 3 inputs and 2 change, third doesn't. Seems close, but can't figure out what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a small change :)

```
$(function() {
    var allInputs = $(":input");
    $(allInputs).keyup(function() {
        $(this).css('font-style', 'normal');

        if($(allInputs).val().length === 0) { // this had to be added inside the event.
           $(this).css('font-style', 'italic');
        }

       preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Comment: @super11 yeah! my bad, the keypress event wouldn't capture the length, as required by us.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to catch up two events keypress and blur.

check this example

```
html 
<body>
<input type="text" class="input-text" placeholder="Enter text" />
</body>

css 
.input-text {
 font-style:italic;
} 
$('.input-text').blur(function(){
   var text_length = $('.input-text').val();
   if(text_length == 0) {
      $('.input-text').css('font-style','italic');
   }else {
      $('.input-text').css('font-style','normal');
   }
});
$('.input-text').keypress(function(){
   var text_length = $('.input-text').val();
   if(text_length == 0) {
      $('.input-text').css('font-style','italic');
   }else {
      $('.input-text').css('font-style','normal');
   }
});
```

[example link](https://jsfiddle.net/r8rk3d37/)